# celeryd not launching startup

Tags: celery, init.d

I am trying to install an init.d script, to run celery for scheduling tasks. I'd like to launch celery automatically at startup.

Here is the steps I followed:

- copied the file [celeryd](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/3.1/extra/generic-init.d/celeryd) and pasted it in folder /etc/init.d/
- created a configuration file celeryd in folder /etc/default/
- update-rc.d celeryd defaults
- reboot via "vagrant halt" and then "vagrant up"

Both files are owned by root:root and have 755 permissions.

I can launch the service manually:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

but it is not being launched automatically.

Running Ubuntu 12.04 in a virtualbox